# CollectionView First And Last Cell remains selected

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

i am using a collectionView which is selectable, and when a user selects the first then the last cell both cells remain selected for some reason idk why.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if (collectionView == self.categoryCollectionView)
    {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ChannelsCategoryCell
        cell?.triangleIndicatorView.isHidden = false
        cell?.categoryLabel.textColor = UIColor.init(named: "ActiveSymbol")
        
        loadChannelList()
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if (collectionView == self.categoryCollectionView)
    {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ChannelsCategoryCell
    
        cell?.triangleIndicatorView.isHidden = true
        cell?.categoryLabel.textColor = UIColor.init(named: "InactiveCategoryText")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    if selectedIndex == indexPath.item {
      cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    } else {
      cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndex = indexPath.item
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: The background color is not relevant to cell selection